# How to quickly estimate the person's level of stress with a mobile based relaxation app?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, experimental-psychology, stress

I'm writing a simple iPhone relaxation app and am thinking of **a very quick test I can do to learn something about the user's level of stress, anxiety, etc.** The objective is to measure how effective the app is or to adjust the length of the session.

I thought of using the following measurement process:

- Ask the user to trace a line with their finger, prior to relaxation
- Repeat the tracing process following relaxation
- Analyze and compare results to the user's previous entry or historic entries for the same user

**Does this approach have any merit or validity? What other simple and quick ways are there to gauge how relaxed or stressed the user is?**

A mobile device, like iPhone has 3 axis accelerometer, gyroscope, magnetometer, and a capacitive touchscreen that does not measure the pressure of a touch.

[image]

Comment: I don't imagine that the line tracing task is a valid (or reliable) measure of stress or anxiety--and also it may not be sensitive enough to detect impairment in fine motor movements (which I assume is what you're trying to measure). You could always try to look for one-item anxiety or stress scales (e.g., http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0895435606003878).

Answer (score 3):

Anxiety and stress are very available states, and since you want to know how people currently *feel* (rather than some more implicit construct), you probably can't do much better than just asking them. A single-item anxiety measure as suggested by mlt should work.

Answer (score 1):

What do you think about quick short-memory tests? It will measure distraction level and anxiety. Problem though is that first one must measure baseline rate of correct responses.
For example, play game [memory](http://www.web-games-online.com/memory/) on 5x5 tile set.

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that the [upcoming Apple Research Kit for iPhone](https://developer.apple.com/researchkit/researchkit-technical-overview.pdf) allows for some kinds of motor and touch activity monitoring. Maybe some of these can be re-purposed to collect data relevant to the original question.

[image]